# How to use Flutter with Mongodb & AWS

Tags: mongodb, flutter, dart, aws-lambda, backend

I am new to development, using flutter and firebase I created a real time blog mobile app. Now I wanted to shift to Mongodb and AWS, I am struck here, I could not figure the process from where to start also could not find any documents to rely on. I feel like I am in post beginner stage, expert guidance will help me a lot. I want to use flutter with MongoDB and AWS, how can I connect these?

Comment: Your post contains no question.

Comment: I am not able to figure how to use mongodb and aws in flutter. Looking for some help on this.